# Redirect the open syscall of resource on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, system-calls

Let me first explain my situation:

I have an old application and don't have any possibility of changing it. This application works with sqlite tables, one of them being a "temporary" database, but does not create temporary tables in memory but rather uses normal tables.

I install this application in a terminal server and the problem is that the application tries to read from a static path from the temporary table.

I need to redirect the "open syscall" to another file, so I want to know if I could do that with some software or by programming it.

Comment: yes - that should be possible (but tough to implement!) though I would strongly advice against doing so in a production scenario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options in order of "preferableness":

1. Create a [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768). Click the link to get a tool for doing this.
2. Use a [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711665/windows-how-to-create-custom-appcompat-shims-application-fixes) if possible.
3. If the above are not possible then you could use Madshi's [madCodeHook](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm) lib to intercept the(*) call. Somebody [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895617/detours-alternative-for-registry-interception) is having a similar question, the discussion there also applies to your situation.

   Be careful though when using API hooking and always ask yourself what would happen if two programs are doing it at the same time. This would likely result in an unstable system a.k.a. a mess.

   (*) You would also have to figure out which call you actually need to hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with a [junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point).